# how to give {% url '' %} to a variable?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this requirement in django template:

```
{% if user.is_admin %}
<a href='{% url 'url_to_admin' %}'>admin url</a>
{% else %}
<a href='{% url 'url_to_other %}'>other url </a>
{% endif %}
```

and now, I want let it more simple, I want let `url` to a variable `xx', like this:

```
if user.is_admin:
    myurl = {% url 'url_to_admin' %}
else:
    myurl = {% url 'url_to_other' %}

<a href={{myurl}} > url </a>
```

But I don't know how to write in django's template?

Comment: Don't think you can write such in django templates.

Comment: What's the issue with using reverse URL.?
See 'url' in this -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/

Answer (score 2):

The `url` tag can be assigned to a variable through using `as`.

```
{% url 'my_url' as foobar %}
{{ foobar }}
```

But that doesn't make sense in the current place where you're using it. Just assign the anchor tags inside of the if/else statements

```
{% if user.is_admin %}
    <a href="{% url 'url_to_admin' %}">admin</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'url_to_other' %}">other</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer, but you may try this:

```
<a href='{% if user.is_admin %}{% url 'url_to_admin' %}{% else %}{% url 'url_to_other' %}'>other url </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you handle it in the views before you render the template, try something like in your view.py
`if User.is_admin:
   url = 'url_to_admin'
else:
   url = 'url_to_other'
render(request, "your_template.html", {'url' : url})`

then you can go ahead and call your url in your template like
`<a href= "{{ url }}>url</a>"`

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
def my_view(request):
    if request.user.is_admin:
        my_url = reverse('my_admin_view')
    else:
        my_url = reverse('my_other_view')
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'my_url': my_url })
```

Using [django.core.urlresolvers.reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)

my_template.html

```
<a href="{{ my_url }}">This is a link</a>
```